# Removing backslash with str_replace

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

So I'm trying to remove a backslash (stored in database as in example - How\'s it going).

What i want to do is to remove that backslash and keep the newlines and spaces aswell.

I know that this does the trick :

```
str_replace('\\', '', $string);
```

but the issue is that I have two other expressions aswell so right now I have:

```
str_replace('\\r\\n', "\r\n", $string);
```

How and where do I put in the '\\', '' in the second example without interferring with the newlines?

I have simply tried `str_replace('\\r\\n\\', "\r\n ', $string)` and so on but I can't get it to work without messing up the newlines.

Anyone who can help me?

EDIT:

What I have now to output the data is:

```
echo nl2br(str_replace('\\r\\n', "\r\n", $string));
```

Which displays a string stored in the db, **How\'s it going?\r\n\r\nROW 3** as:

```
How\'s it going?

ROW 3
```

In a paragraph tag.

So what I want is to keep the newlines intact. Stripslashes removes the newlines and puts the output in one row.

When storing the data I'm using this clean function:

```
function clean($mysqli, $var) {
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    return $mysqli->real_escape_string($var);
}
```

What could I adjust to keep the newlines and also remove the single backslash in words like *It's, what's, how's* etc..

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Comment: Whats your desired output for How\'s it going

Comment: `str_replace('\\\'', "'", $string);`

Comment: stripslashes($string)

Comment: Sadly those methods removes the new lines aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is considered a good practice but what I did was:

```
$output = nl2br(str_replace('\\r\\n', "\r\n", $string));
echo str_replace('\\', "", $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `stripslashes` function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Stripslashes removes the newlines aswell.

Comment: Yes. But if you have one slash in newlines wildcards it is mistake of writing in db. If you can not fix it, use `str_replace('\\r\\n', "\\\\r\\\\n", $string);` before `stripslashes`